# How to assign RootVisual from another class

Tags: c#, silverlight, interop, scriptable

In `silverlight` Im trying to assign the `RootVisual` object from another class.

The reason for this is that JavaScript will be performing some `Ajax` queries and will need to dynamically change the `UI element` at any time.

Here is what I have done so far, it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class MyClass
{

    private UIElement _rootVisual;

    public MyClass(UIElement root)
    {
        _rootVisual = root;
    }

    public bool SetVisual(int id)
    {

        switch(id) {
           case 0: 
               this._rootVisual = new MyUI1();
               break;
           default: 
               this._rootVisual = new MyUI2();
               break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**Here is my App.xaml.cs**

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create A Scriptable object
        this.myclass= new MyClass( this.RootVisual );


        // Register Scriptable for JS Interop 
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("jsMyClass", myclass);



        //Load the initial UI but should be able to access/change later via JS
        myclass.LoadScene(0);


    }



}
```

**Here is the JS that calls the Scriptable myClas**

```
function _test()
{
     slControl = document.getElementById("SilverlightControl");

     slControl.Content.jsMyClass.SetVisual(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to keep the root visual the same but change the content within it.

So in your App.cs file you do this

```
            //Setup a root content user control so we can swap out the content depending on what we want to show
        UserControl RootContent = new UserControl();
        RootContent.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        RootContent.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        this.RootVisual = RootContent;
        (this.RootVisual as UserControl).Content = new SplashScreenView();
```

And then when you want to switch to a different view you can just do this

```
(App.Current.RootVisual as UserControl).Content = new Views.PreQualView();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I figured out this too but didn't have time to update my question.
Im now trying to implement a transition from one scene to another but thats another question I guess. Thanks again